# Count characters in user input, if not divisible by three, then trim excess characters

Tags: python

Just getting started learning Python and have a question. Given a user input of a DNA sequence that can be any number of characters long, how would I go about printing a result that trims excess characters from the end of the string and returns a result?

Example: user inputs a DNA sequence of "ACG CTA TCG C".
The desired result would be "ACG CTA TCG" (groups of 3, excess trimmed from result). If the user input was "ACC TAG TAG AT," the result would be "ACC TAG TAG". And so on with any input the user enters.

Here's what I have so far:

```
# Request user input, convert to uppercase and remove white spaces
dna_input = input("Enter a DNA sequence: ").upper()
dna_input = dna_input.replace(" ", "")

# Empty variable to hold reading frame result
reading_1 = ""
chars = 0

# Check that input is valid - only contain letters A, C, G, T
if set(dna_input) <= {"A", "C", "T", "G"}:
    
    # First reading frame
    # Return codons in order, trim excess
    
    chars = len(dna_input) # how many characters
    
    if chars % 3 == 0: # check if chars are divisible by three
        for j in dna_input:
            reading_1 += j
    print("First reading frame:", reading_1)
    
    else:
        print("Need to do something different. How to trim excess?")

# If invalid letters used, return error   
else:
    print("Try again using a valid input.")
```

I'm also getting a syntax error with the inner `else` statement and am not sure why...

Comment: BTW, for counting the characters of a string you don't need a loop. You already have calculated the length with `len`. So replace that loop with `chars = len(dna_input)`.

Comment: *if*, *print*, *else* are at the same level. Indent *print* 4 spaces to the right.

Comment: Concerning your problem: use integer division (`//`). `9 // 3` will give you `3`, `8 // 3` is `2`.  In the second case the length should be `6` (`2 * 3`). Next thing you have to know how to get a part of a string. Run `print('Hello'[:4])` and `print('Hello'[:3])` and understand the result. Resulting code: `dna_input = dna_input[:(len(dna_input) // 3) * 3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a regular expression for this

`[ACTG]{3}` will match any sequence of length 3 using the characters {A,C,T,G}
and then `" ".join()` will join them together with a space in-between.

```
def trim_chain(chain):
    print(" ".join(re.findall(r"[ACTG]{3}",chain)))
    
trim_chain("ABC ACT CTG TGG TC")
```

Comment: That's a nice approach.

Comment: This works! As I'm still learning some of the basics, is there a way to do this without importing extra modules?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here `print("First reading frame:", reading_1)`, this `print` has to be indented. This break the `if/else` logic.

```
# Request user input, convert to uppercase and remove white spaces
dna_input = input("Enter a DNA sequence: ").upper()
dna_input = dna_input.replace(" ", "")

# Empty variable to hold reading frame result
reading_1 = ""
chars = 0

# Check that input is valid - only contain letters A, C, G, T
if set(dna_input) <= {"A", "C", "T", "G"}:
    
    # First reading frame
    # Return codons in order, trim excess
    
    for i in range(len(dna_input)): # count characters
        chars += 1
    print("There are", chars, "characters.")
    
    if chars % 3 == 0: # check if chars are divisible by three
        for j in dna_input:
            reading_1 += j
        print("First reading frame:", reading_1)
    
    else:
        print("Need to do something different. How to trim excess?")

# If invalid letters used, return error   
else:
    print("Try again using a valid input.")
```

I hope I've helped!